# Refactor use of this in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code in and example app and need to use it in a functional component:

```js
 ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
```

How can I assign the ref in an functional component?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Actually sorry - I know it's the rules, but if I want to thank someone, I will. Thanks.

Comment: I would urge you to change your mind if you can. It sounds like you are proud of creating work for volunteer curators, and you forget they are working for your benefit. Stack Overflow runs on volunteer effort: editing, closing, curating, tidying. It is thankless work, and never-ending.

Comment: Please read: [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)

Comment: Please read: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

Comment: These links are canonical expressions of posting and editing policy, and it is helpful if everyone can abide by them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`React.useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook.

**Example:**

```
import React from "react";

function MyAwesomeFxnComponent() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  return (
      <Carousel ref={ref} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With functional components you can use refs like this:

```
// Import react useRef hooks
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export function CarouselWrapper {
  // create your reference
  const carouselRef = useRef(null);

  return (
   // Pass ref to your carousel component
   <Carousel ref={carouselRef} />  
  )
};
```

Here you can read docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref